# Rewriting Ruby #inject (#reduce) using recursion?

Tags: arrays, ruby, inject, proc, accumulator

New to coding and have gone through some of the more commonly used methods in Ruby, monkey patching them to gain a better understanding of how each works (which btw has helped a massive amount).

Now I'm again doing the same, but for ones that I previously iterated through, I am using recursion. My question is:

I am creating my own `#inject` method for the `Array` class, and I want to write this recursively. The method would allow an optional accumulator to be passed, as well as a proc. How would this be done using the following format?

```
class Array
  def my_inject(accum = nil, &prc)
    #code
  end 
end
```

Also, do I need to worry about mutating the original array, should I use `#dup`? Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: what do you want to write inside `my_inject`?

Comment: Can't tell if you are joking or not, but if not I would like to write a method that does the same thing as Ruby's Enumerable #inject (#reduce) method, for the Array class, as stated in the Original Post

Comment: ^ using recursion

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An alternative implementation

```
class Array
  def aggregate(accumulator = nil, &sumator)
    return accumulator if empty?

    drop(1).aggregate(accumulator ? sumator.(accumulator, first) : first, &sumator)
  end
end
```

---

As for should you worry about mutating the original - in short - yes. Usually methods in Ruby don't mutate objects if possible and make a copy. There are often times bang (`!`) alternatives that do. Said *"dangerous"* methods mutate the original in place instead of returning a copy. However, in this situation this wouldn't make sense. The original is an array and the result is the sum.

As for mutating the original and returning the result separately, unless you have a real performance (or other) consideration, you shouldn't do it. It's unintuitive and can lead to confusing situations.

Comment: hmm, returned nil for me..  I tried with array = [1, 2, 3] , prc = Proc.new {|x,y| x + y}, and with and without an acumulator

Comment: @Zezuz try again, I had a minor mistake in the original version.

Comment: Works, Thanks! I like that you used #drop, instead of creating a different array like I did using #dup. (since drop doesn't mutate)

Comment: also makes it so you dont have to write 'array.method'  since self is not necessary..   and sorry, I cant upvote because I'm a newb still. would if I could :(

Comment: @Zezuz, glad it was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I think I got it!

```
class Array
  def my_inject(acc=nil, &prc)  
    return acc if empty?    
    acc = self.shift if acc.nil? 

    acc = prc.call(acc, self.first)    
    self.shift    
    my_inject(acc, &prc)    
  end    
end
```

My only question is would this be problematic/ does it mutate the original array?

EDIT: Added version that does not mutate original.

```
class Array
  def my_inject(acc=nil, &prc)  
    new_arr = self.dup
    return acc if empty?    
    acc = new_arr.shift if acc.nil? 

    acc = prc.call(acc, self.first)    
    new_arr.shift    
    my_inject(acc, &prc)    
  end    
end
```

Comment: Thanks @ndn, I added a version that does not. Although, I'm not sure if that was the best way to do so